# Insert data in Sql Server from Event Hub using Azure Function

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I'm using Azure function to insert data in SQL Server from Event Hub.

I write this code to insert data in SQL Server but i can insert **only one message per execution**.

```
public static void Run(string[] eventHubMessages, TraceWriter log)
{

  SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
  cnn.ConnectionString = /* my connection string */;
  cnn.Open();

  log.Info("Connection open");

  foreach(var item in eventHubMessages)
  {
    if(item.StartsWith("{") && item.EndsWith("}"))
    {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TelemetriaAttiva.ImportEvents", cnn); // call stored procedure
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Events", item);
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
}
```

The stored procedure code is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [TelemetriaAttiva].[ImportEvents]  @Events NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS  BEGIN 
INSERT INTO TelemetriaAttiva.Events (IDType, PayloadType, SerialNumber, Cid, 
Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Sid, InsDate, InsUser) 
SELECT idtype, payloadtype, serialnumber, cid, year, month, day, hour, 
minute, second, sid, insdate, insuser FROM OPENJSON(@Events)
WITH(
    IDType varchar(50) '$.idtype',
    PayloadType varchar(50) '$.payloadtype',
    SerialNumber varchar(50) '$.serialnumber',
    Cid varchar(50) '$.cid',
    Year varchar(50) '$.year',
    Month varchar(50) '$.month',
    Day varchar(50) '$.day',
    Hour varchar(50) '$.hour',
    Minute varchar(50) '$.minute',
    Second varchar(50) '$.second',
    Sid varchar(50) '$.sid',
    InsDate varchar(50) '$.insdate',
    InsUser varchar(100) '$.insuser'
) 
END 
GO
```

Can someone help me to insert on Sql Server **all of data** that Event Hub has inside?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Search for Bulk Insert in c#,http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/insert-bulk-records-into-database-using-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/

Comment: If you have to call a SP and you can't change it, then there is no way to call it for all events at the same time. If you can change it, please specify what it does and how it can be changed.

Comment: Add a log statement after your cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() - if a log entry is arriving for each message then your issue is in the stored proc somewhere. Can you post the code of the proc?

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft I post the code of stored procedure

Comment: Proc looks ok - did you add the log entry too? Are you getting the number of messages you expect?

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft No, i'm not getting the number of messages that i'm expect.. because I think that only a message that trigger the function is inserted in database, and the other are messages aren't inserted.

Comment: So the problem is probably before you even get to your function - you need to look in to the producer - the code that is generating the messages that is sent to the event hub that your function is then consuming.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft In my Event Hub there are thousand and thousand of message that are sent at the function every 1 minute (Azure stream analytics with tumbling window)

Comment: @CarloDonzelli Are you sure item.StartsWith("{") && item.EndsWith("}") is the right filter?

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft yes, because sometimes the json that arrived from Event Hub is not valid, and with this if i try to eliminate the json that not start with { and end with }

Comment: @CarloDonzelli you will have to log and debug end to end, I don't think your original question is valid any more.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft ok, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks like you could try the following:

1. Concat all the messages in one JSON array, e.g.

   ```cs
   var items = $"[{string.Join(",", eventHubMessages)}]";
   ```
2. Pass them all in one call to the stored procedure (same call as now, but without any `foreach` loop)

   ```cs
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Events", items);
   ```
3. Adjust your stored procedure to expect an array of items in JSON instead of the single item.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I try :)